# How do I apply JHtmlSidebar to add a sidebar to my admin view?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

I can't find any tutorials on how to use the `JHtmlSidebar` Utility Class.

This comes close to it: [Creating a toolbar for your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_toolbar_for_your_component), but it is very vague. It mentions `$this->sidebar`, which suggest that the View class should have an attribute sidebar. But sidebar attribute doesn't exist in the View class.

I tried using this:

```
JHtmlSidebar::addEntry('test','test',0);
echo $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();
```

It does indeed echo the sidebar, but it sits at top or bottom of my view, not on the side. I'm just wondering if there is a way to let Joomla do the rendering for me, instead of creating my own layout.

Some help or links to useful tutorial on the use of admin side bar would be much appreciated. Thank you.

com_helloworld/views/helloworld/view.html.php:

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class HelloWorldViewHelloWorld extends JViewLegacy {
    public function display($tpl = NULL){
        $this->addToolbar();
        $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();
        }
    }

    protected function addToolbar(){
        require_once JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/helloworld .php';
        JToolBarHelper::title( 'Hello World', 'helloworld' );
        JToolBarHelper::addNew();
        JToolBarHelper::deleteList();
        JToolBarHelper::editList();
        JToolBarHelper::preferences('com_helloworld', '500');
        xProfileHelper::addSubmenu('helloworld');
    }
}
```

com_helloworld/helpers/helloworld.php:

```
class HelloWorldHelper extends JHelperContent
{
    public static function addSubmenu($vName)
    {
        JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
            'test',
            'index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=helloworld',
            $vName == 'profile'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You firstly need to create a helper file, for example:

```
administrator/components/com_helloworld/helpers/helloworld.php
```

and in this file, add the following:

```
class HelloWorldHelper extends JHelperContent
{
    public static function addSubmenu($vName)
    {
        JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
            'test',
            'index.php?option=com_hellowworld&view=VIEWNAME',
            $vName == 'banners'
        );
    }
}
```

Change `VIEWNAME` and the value for `$vName` to the view for your component that you wish to add the sidebar to.

Then, in your **view.html.php** file, call it using the following:

```
HelloWorldHelper::addSubmenu('VIEWNAME');
```

and of course, the following is required to render the sidebar which you can put below the code above:

```
$this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();
```

If you have a look at the Banners component that comes packaged with Joomla, it will provide a good example.

### Update:

If forgot to mention, inside your `addToolbar()` function in the **view.html.php** file, you will need to call the helper file like so:

```
require_once JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/hellowworld.php';
```

### Update 2:

Sorry, I'm not on the ball today. You will need to add the following to your **default.php** in `views/VIEWNAME/tmpl`:

```
<div id="j-sidebar-container" class="span2">
    <?php echo $this->sidebar; ?>
</div>
<div id="j-main-container" class="span10">
     // Main part of the component view
</div>
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how easy/difficult it would be to use the sidebar for a component's F/E?

Comment: @GDP, by "F/E", are you referring to the frontend?

Comment: Thanks, I used your code and followed the banners example. But now it's telling me "Fatal error: Class 'HelloWorldHelper' not found in ..\com_helloworld\views\myview\view.html.php on" Do I need to instantiate the helper somewhere? I've never used one before...

Comment: I made sure it's the same by copying. PHPStorm is even able to link the file. So I don't understand why it's not in scope when I test it.

Comment: @user3804927 - See my updated answer. Sorry I forgot about that :/

Comment: The error is gone, but the sidebar isn't showing. Again, if I echo render code, the sidebar shows, on top of my component. I just don't get how the layout is placed on the left hand. I will paste the code as is, hopefully you can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @user3804927 - See the second update in my answer. Sorry about all this confusion

Comment: I still can't get it to work. But I can sort of understand now. It does answer my original question regarding the use of layout. Joomla doesn't do this automatically like JToolbarHelper. It's like 2am here. I'll debug tomorrow and report on the issue then. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: It is working now. I had to find out how to use layout and pass variables etc. And got it thank you! I'll mark this as the answer.