# How to change styling of Joomla Collapsible Sidebar in Backend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, custom-component

I have created sidebar for my custom component by using the documentation -

> [How do I apply JHtmlSidebar to add a sidebar to my admin view?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/how-do-i-apply-jhtmlsidebar-to-add-a-sidebar-to-my-admin-view/4091#4091)

I have to add some styling to the Joomla Collapsible Sidebar in admin side.
I have searched but nothing found related to this.

As you can see in the image(this is just an example), Now I need to add some styling or change the design/layout of the sidebar.

[image: Change Joomla Collapsible Sidebar in Backend]

How to change the styling/layout of the collapsible sidebar?

Also is it possible ***without hacking core***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as per my answer from the link you provided, you'll need to add the following to your **default.php**:

```
<div id="j-sidebar-container" class="span2">
    <?php echo $this->sidebar; ?>
</div>
```

So you can simply add an extra class after `span2`, for example:

```
<div id="j-sidebar-container" class="span2 mySidebar">
```

Then apply your own custom styling. For example

```
.mySidebar a {
     color: #FF0
}
```

if it's structural changes you need to make or adding your own classes inside of the sidebar, you'll need to make a Layout Override for the following file:

```
ROOT/layouts/joomla/sidebars/submenu.php
```

Be sure that you **override** is and **do not** edit it directly, as this will apply your changes for every extension that calls the Submenu layout.

Comment: thanks for answering @Lodder But I wanted to change all the elements like adding new styles in lists, adding own classes on the ul, select tags

Comment: Ah, in which case you going to need to perform a layout override for the following file: `ROOT/layouts/joomla/sidebars/submenu.php`. Note the word "**override**"...do not edit this file directly

Comment: you just gave me an awesome idea :) Ill just create an layout overrider for this. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Joomler - updated ;)