# How to get sidebar in joomla admin

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, administrator, custom-component

I am new to joomla.

I am trying to develop component.

How can I have sidebar in Joomla admin component.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Please check this - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4091/3637

Answer (score 0):

Look at an example:
**administrator/components/com_installer/views/default/view.php**
In the view it renders the sidebar:

```
    // Render side bar.
    $this->sidebar = JHtmlSidebar::render();
```

Later in a template it outputs the sidebar

```
    <?php echo $this->sidebar; ?>
```

**But how does it know what to be in the sidebar?**
In the main controller
**administrator/components/com_installer/controller.php**
it established the sidebar

```
        // Load the submenu.
        InstallerHelper::addSubmenu($vName);
```

And if you look at the helpder, you can see that it just adds common buttons to the sidebar

```
    JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
        JText::_('COM_INSTALLER_SUBMENU_INSTALL'),
        'index.php?option=com_installer',
        $vName == 'install'
    );
    JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
        JText::_('COM_INSTALLER_SUBMENU_UPDATE'),
        'index.php?option=com_installer&view=update',
        $vName == 'update'
    );
```

So resuming:
Add buttons like this:

```
JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
    JText::_('COM_INSTALLER_SUBMENU_INSTALL'),
    'index.php?option=com_installer',
    $vName == 'install'
);
```

Render sidebar like this

```
echo JHtmlSidebar::render();
```