# As JSubmenuHelper is deprecated, how to migrate to JHtmlSidebar?

Tags: joomla-3.x, migration, joomla-4.x, sidebar

The only source I found about this is from this post: [Replacing JSubmenuHelper with JHtmlSidebar / Administrative menu in Joomla 4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22475/replacing-jsubmenuhelper-with-jhtmlsidebar-administrative-menu-in-joomla-4)

The issue here is that I tried it, and it doesn't show the Sidebar if I try it with `JHtmlSidebar`.

Here is the Code:

```
public function render($config = array())
{
    $config = new KObjectConfigJson($config);
    $config->append(array(
        'toolbar' => null
    ));

    foreach ($config->toolbar->getCommands() as $command)
    {
        if(!empty($command->href)) {
            $command->href = $this->getTemplate()->route($command->href);
        }

        JSubmenuHelper::addEntry($this->getObject('translator')->translate($command->label), $command->href, $command->active);

    }

    return '';
}
```

In this, `JSubmenuHelper::addEntry` should be replaced with the `JHtmlSidebar` function.

I tried to change the line to

```
JHtmlSidebar::addEntry($this->getObject('translator')->translate($command->label), $command->href, $command->active);
```

and to

```
JHtmlSidebar::render($this->getObject('translator')->translate($command->label), $command->href, $command->active);
```

but on with `addEntry` the sidebar is hidden and with `render()` there is no content in it.

What is wrong with the attempts that I already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will firstly need to create a helper class that extends `ContentHelper`, like so:

> administrator/components/com_mycomponent/Helper/MyComponentHelper.php

```
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ContentHelper;

class MyComponentHelper extends ContentHelper
{
    protected $config = null;

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = new KObjectConfigJson($config);
        $this->config->append(array(
            'toolbar' => null
        ));
    }

    public static function addSubmenu()
    {
        foreach ($this->config->toolbar->getCommands() as $command)
        {
            if (!empty($command->href))
            {
                $command->href = $this->getTemplate()->route($command->href);
            }

            \JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
                $this->getObject('translator')->translate($command->label),
                $command->href,
                $command->active
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Then in the following directory:

> administrator/components/com_mycomponent/controller.php

You'll want to load the class, using `JLoader`, like so:

```
JLoader::register('MyComponentHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_mycomponent/helpers/contact.php');
```

Once done, you will need to instantiate the class in your view.html.php:

```
MyComponentHelper::addSubmenu();
```

---

**Notes:**

- As far as I know, there is no namespaced version of `\JHtmlSidebar` so I'm not sure if it's going to be supported or replaced in J4.
- I haven't tested this as I don't really work with components
- You will need to add the `getObject()` method to the class or change the `$this->getObject()` reference if it's coming from a different class.

Hope this helps